# parameter lost when the function is called

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

I have a weird thing.
When I call a function from my service, the service lost all the parameters.
I don't know when and why.

The debug says that there's is the parameters when they get in the class and then, nothing.
I make a similar function in another service and it works. Its realy weird.

Look (debug print) :

c.f.timesheet.web.rest.AppUserResource Enter: getAllAppUsersByCompany() with argument[s] = [1, AppUserCriteria{}, Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: undefined: DESC,id: ASC]]

c.f.timesheet.web.rest.AppUserResourceREST request to get AppUsers by company id: 1

c.f.timesheet.service.AppUserService  Enter: findByCompany() with argument[s] = [1, Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: undefined: DESC,id: ASC]]

c.f.timesheet.service.AppUserService :Request to get all AppUsers by company id **!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The problem** the id is missing

Exception in findByCompany() with cause = 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: undefined of: com.freemind.timesheet.domain.AppUser [select appUser from com.freemind.timesheet.domain.AppUser appUser where appUser.id=?1 order by appUser.undefined desc, appUser.id asc]'

Here's the code:

AppUserRessource:

```
@GetMapping("/app-users/company/{id}")//tayo
public ResponseEntity<List<AppUserDTO>> getAllAppUsersByCompany(@PathVariable Long id,Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get AppUsers by company id: {}", id);
    Page<AppUserDTO> page = appUserService.findByCompany(id,pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(page.getContent());
}
```

AppUserService

```
   public Page<AppUserDTO> findByCompany(Long id,Pageable pageable){//?
        log.debug("Request to get all AppUsers by company id", id);
        return  appUserRepository.findByCompany(id,pageable).map(appUserMapper::toDto);
    }
```

the query:

```
   @Query("select appUser from AppUser appUser where appUser.id=?1")
    Page<AppUser> findByCompany( Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Do You have any idea?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 5):

Your debug statement is wrong

```
log.debug("Request to get all AppUsers by company id", id);
```

should be

```
log.debug("Request to get all AppUsers by company id {}", id);
```

The error message says

```
order by appUser.undefined desc, appUser.id asc
```

So the problem is the order by statement, which has undefined in it. It seems like your paging request is not formed correctly on the client side, that is what you should investigate.

Comment: Indeed thank you. So the error in my request is something else.

Comment: Are you using javascript on the client? That's probably where the undefined is coming from, when the paging is being worked out.

Comment: I'm using Angular. I see the issue but don't know how to solve it. I have a sorting function send to the backend => [number: 0, size 20, sort: undefined: DESC,internal_user_id: ASC]]. It knows the id for the asc but it doesn't want for the desc. There's the function  const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
    if (this.predicate !== 'internal_user_id') {
      result.push('internal_user_id');
    }
    return result;

Comment: What are you trying to sort by?

Comment: By the id. I saw the error, wasn't the good string as predicate. Now it works. Thank you! : )

Comment: @Girbouille you should accept Vlad's answer